# Error: (-36, 'I/O error (bummers)') while copying files on High Sierra(Mac OS 10.13)

Tags: macos, python-2.7, macos-high-sierra

I am facing an issue while copying some files using the shutil.copyfile() method of python. The command fails with

Error: (-36, 'I/O error (bummers)')

This issue surfaced after upgrading the mac from Sierra(10.12.6) to High Sierra(10.13). The problem is, the issue is very hard to reproduce and occurs randomly. I have checked apple docs and have not found anything related to this issue. Is there any solution for this?

Comment: I do not know the answer to your question. However I was facing the same problem while connecting to a remote drive wirelessly.

I checked http://cnet.com/news/possibilities-for-overcoming-finder-error-36-in-os-x/ but none of the options worked for me. 

Finally I went raw with this problem. FileZilla (or many other FTP GUI clients might work). I downloaded one from https://filezilla-project.org/download.php?type=client and there is no need to install, just double click the program and connect to ftp server, and start download/upload. All good.